# easy_install requires admin rights on Windows

Tags: python, windows-server-2008-r2, python-2.6, easy-install

Python is installed in a directory all users have full access to, but when I run easy_install, a consent window appears asking for administrator credentials. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution:

> easy_install.cmd

```
@echo off
C:\Python26\python.exe C:\Python26\Scripts\easy_install-script.py %*
```

This script does not require admin rights.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how this solves the problem?  Please confirm that executing the same command directly from the shell reproduces the problem in the question.  I suspect you've retried this on another computer and it suddenly works because of some security/configuration issues.

Comment: @André: what command do you mean? `python.exe` by itself does not require admin rights, so the above script does not require admin rights as well. But `easy_install.exe` needs administrator privileges for some reason. I encountered this problem on many computers with Windows 7/2008.

Comment: That's odd, I was under the impression that `easy_install` tests for writability to the Python packages folder, not for having administrator privileges.  I guess that this works because Python is installed in a location where you have write access without requiring administrator privileges.  If Python was installed in the `Program Files` directory, then this solution might not work...

Comment: @André: Sure, I never install Python into `Program Files`. I prefer per-user installations.

Answer (score 1):

Is this not what you would expect? On every computer I've ever used, admin privileges are required to make any type of modifications that will affect all users.

Comment: Admin privileges are ususally required when ordinary users cannot make modifications. I have full access to the Python installation. And I expect that admin privileges are not required to change it.

Comment: You have full access, but so would any other user, so any changes you make would affect everyone else. Which, again, is the sort of thing that typically requires admin privileges.

Comment: Maybe this [user account control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511445.aspx) page has the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe rights needed for directory. So it can be changed with key --install-dir